# Project load fails for some projects targeting .Net 4.6 in VS2013

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I have a solution with a number of C# projects targeting .Net 4.6 and one native C++ project (no CLR). After using the solution with VS2015 I now get errors when trying to open the solution in VS2013 with half the projects failing to load.

The native C++ project and some of the C# projects give the error:

> error  : A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(TargetPlatformVersion)" that evaluates to "10.0.10069.0" instead of a number, in condition "'$(TargetPlatformVersion)' > '8.0'".  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

I'm not sure why some projects correctly load and others don't, however, it does look like all C# projects which reference NuGet packages fail.

Is there a way to fix these errors and allow the solution and projects to be opened in both VS2013 and VS2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out various changes to project files I found that removing the following line from the native C++ project then allowed all projects in the solution to load correctly.

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10069.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

However, after loading I then found that I couldn't build the native project because of the error:

> error MSB8020: The build tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found.

Even though the vcxproj specifies `ToolsVersion="14.0"` it appears that Visual Studio 2013 will use 12.0 for C++ projects. In the project's properties the `Platform toolset` says `v140 (not installed)`. Changing this to `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)` would allow the project to build in both VS2013 and VS2015, though obviously using the older 12.0 tools rather than 14.0. Instead I added the following lines to my project file:

```
<PlatformToolset Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '12.0'">v120</PlatformToolset>
<PlatformToolset Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' >= '14.0'">v140</PlatformToolset>
```

Now VS2013 will use the `v120` `Platform toolset` and VS2105 (and later) will use `v140`.

After building with VS 2015 the project file may have a `TargetPlatformVersion` and/or `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` line added. If the value is `10.0.10240.0` or another Windows 10 version then the project won't load in VS 2013 as it doesn't like the non-decimal value. This can be fixed by changing the value to `8.1`, telling Visual Studio to use the Windows Kit for Windows 8.1 rather than Windows 10.

**Note:**
Even though you can target .Net 4.6 with VS2013 it doesn't understand C# 6 so will give errors if you try and use any of the new language features. Similarly, targeting `v120` for the C++ project prevents you using newer language features supported in VS2015.

Comment: This answer is for C++ primarily. I met the same error message for C# where an unsuccessful update before might have corrupted MSBuild 12. The fix is to repair Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

Comment: Can I remove WindowsTargetPlatformVersion?